# how to redirect the browser during an ajax call (made using jQuery) in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am facing a problem of redirecting the site while in an ajax call..

here is what i wanna do :

1. make an ajax call to the server.
2. it goes to a certain process, if an error occurs, i should send to the error page, else resume.

now the problem is when in the server side, if i use :

```
header('Location: error.php');
```

It doesnt redirect the page, infact it just brings the data of that page (the whole html) to the javascript success function.

The problem is that i have made a generic library  both on the javascript side (to call the ajax) and on the server side.

i need to redirect the page through the server side. i tried adding a js code for

```
 window.location='error.php';
```

but didnt get any success

Answer (score 3):

Why not return an error that the Ajax query can understand instead?

```
if ($error)
 {  header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo "A database error has occurred. etc.etc.";
    die();
 }
```

this will trigger the Ajax request's error callback (if in jQuery). The echoed text will be in the response body.

You can also look for a more fitting [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have an error handler in your ajax lib. In the server you send back either the correct html or an error code in the header plus the URL to redirect to in the body. In the ajax lib the error code in the header will trigger the error handler. In the error handler you can redirect using window.location = 'page_returned_by_server'

Answer (score 0):

If an error occurs, simply echo the url of the errorpage. For example, using JSON:

Server-side:

```
echo '{error: "error.php"}';
```

Client-side:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
    .success(function() {
        var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        if obj.error {
            window.location = obj.error;
        }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the $.ajaxError() global AJAX event?

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    alert('An AJAX error occurred in script: ' + settings.url);
    console.log(event, jqxhr, settings, exception);
});
```

In your main JS lib could do the trick and you can add any type of redirect you like.

[Here's the official jQuery documentation..](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)